# Passing variable argument list from Objective-C method to C function

Tags: objective-c, wrapper, objective-c-runtime, variadic-functions

I want to create a wrapper class for some Objective-C Runtime methods for easier testing (stubbing etc.), and I would like to know how I handle the passing of variable arguments from an Objective-C method to a C function.

For example, I want to wrap a C function with the following function signature:

```
id objc_msgSend(id theReceiver, SEL theSelector, ...)
```

I understand I can use the "..." operator for the Objective-C method, but how can I pass this to the C function?

```
- (id)msgSend:(id)theReceiver selector:(SEL)theSelector, ...
{
    return objc_msgSend(theReceiver, theSelector, ...) // <-- how to pass variable arguments?
}
```

Comment: The duplicate asks about method to method passing of a variable argument list but the answers apply to this question as well.

Comment: While this question is "similar" to the other question, I disagree that it is a "duplicate."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. Variadic arguments cannot be passed down. The closest thing you can do is look for a variation of the function which takes a `va_list` instead of variadic arguments, then initialize a `va_list` and pass it to the function.

Back in the old days, `objc_msgSend()` had such a companion function called `objc_msgSendv()`. It has been deprecated and removed since then. But with that function, you could do this:

```
- (id)sendMessageTo:(id)selfish selector:(SEL)sel, ...
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, sel);
    id retVal = objc_msgSendv(selfish, sel, args);
    va_end args;
    return retVal;
}
```

Comment: Bummer, this will be the second useful function that has been deprecated that I've bumped into in the last month or so.

Comment: @5StringRyan Yes, too bad Apple removed it :(

Comment: It isn't that useful as it only works with methods that were declared variadic in the first place, which is very very few.   I.e. you couldn't use this as a generic forwarding mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this with *pure C*. But for this purpose [libffi](http://sourceware.org/libffi/) exists, which is (or has been) used by Apple for language bridging, too. I used it in my AOP framework. It works very well.